# MouseClick in ubuntu + autokey

Tags: ubuntu, automation

I am relatively new to using autokey so I am wondering if anyone can tell me where I am going wrong with this particular script. I am writing a simple script that logs into a website.  The problem is that when I load the page sometimes a small popup appears from the website.  Using the mouse if I left click it disappears and the cursor moves to the textbox.  I am trying to simulate this behavior with autokey with the following

```
system.exec_command("google-chrome --new-window https://webauth.umbc.edu/umbcLogin?return_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebauth.umbc.edu%2Fidp%2FAuthn%2FRemoteUser&Service=shib2-idp&Expires=60&reqexts=LogoutAppUri%25aHR0cHMlM0ElMkYlMkZ3ZWJhdXRoLnVtYmMuZWR1JTJGc2hpYmJvbGV0aCUyRnRpY2tldGxvZ291dC5jZ2klM0Zjb29raWUlM0RVTUJDQXV0aFRpY2tldHNoaWIyLWlkcA%3D%3D%2CWebAuthParamsInURL%2Cmethod%25R0VU%2CRCSS")
Sleep,5000
MouseClick, left
```

However it is not achieving the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Sleep, is not an Autokey/Python function. The correct format is "time.sleep(nnn)" set in seconds. A delay of 5000 seconds is 83+ minutes. The syntax "Sleep, 5000" is an Autohotkey function in Windows, where the units are in milliseconds.

https://documentation.help/AutoHotKey-Functions/Sleep.htm